# Run Tor browser in the background?

Tags: onion-services, ubuntu

If I was to run a tor service on a real server such as Ubuntu Server, is there a background mode to run tor in, or does the browser have to be open at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a tor hidden service, you should use tor, not tor browser. You can run tor as a daemon.

```
sudo apt-get install tor
tor
```

Make sure you properly [set up your hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) too.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, you should add the Tor Project repository so you have the latest version of Tor: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

Comment: also you should run tor as a system service daemon, e.g. `service tor start` so that it runs as a low privileged user rather than, in this example, a user with sudo capabilities.